# hide(fade) element when scroll down element within viewport

Tags: jquery, css

I have a sticky link scrolling down to #id. But I don't know how to fade out the sticky link if user scrolls to that point anyway. Is there a way to fade out the sticky-link element once viewport sees top of element?

```
  $(".scrollt0").click(function(event) {
var $target = $(this.hash);

event.preventDefault();
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $target.offset().top-220}, 'slow');
$target.addClass('hilight');

setTimeout(function() {$target.removeClass('hilight');}, 1000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $header = $(".profile-header"),
        $clone = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("clone"));

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("body").toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 310));
    });
});
```

Comment: If the `offset().top` of the element minus the window `scrollTop()` is 0, then the user has scrolled enough that the top part of the element is at the very bottom of the viewport

Comment: Sorry I am new, can you elaborate?

Comment: The `offset().top` of an element is the distance from the very top of the page to the element.  So say an element is 1000px down the page.  Then, if the user scrolls down 400px, they have 600px to go until the element will be just outside the bottom of the viewport.  If they scroll down 1000px, the element will be just outside the viewport but not visible.  Any more scrolling down will cause part of the element to be in the viewport.  So if your concern is to check if the element is in the viewport, these two values, along with potentially the offsetHeight of the element, are your big concerns

Comment: Issue is that the element is a varied px amount down as it's user content. It will have to use the element as a reference of when to start fading no?

Comment: Yep, that's why you have to get the `offset().top` of the element.  You get that dynamic value that way.  You're already doing this sort of logic for the $target element.

Comment: Are you trying to hide a specific element? `.hide()` accepts an argument for duration. `$target.hide(1000);` for example.